# Non-aquisition of British Citizenship certificate has obscure date

Tags: united-kingdom, south-african-citizens

I am a South African living in the UK. I am trying to apply for retention of my South African citizenship.

I have the certificate from the UK Border Agency that says that I am not British but when I took this to the South African embassy they would not accept it because the date (26/08/2014) has a scribble around the 8. It looks like the pen slipped when the person signed it.

The embassy asked me to produce the receipt for the certificate and I didn't think I needed to keep that so I don't have it anymore.

Does anyone know how I can get this receipt or who I need to contact at the UK Border Agency to get this corrected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve this I landed up writing a letter and sending it to the same address that I requested the original certificate from. I included a photocopy of the certificate and highlighted the obscure date and explained that the embassy would not accept it.

I received a letter back saying that I should fill in the forms again and send a cover letter requesting that the certificate should be issued free of charge because of this problem.